# How to Calculate Industry Medians with Own Firm Excluded

Tags: r, median

I need to create a new column with the median ETR variable within a certain industry (SIC) for a sample of firms.

However, I need to exclude the own firm before calculating the industry (SIC) median for ETR.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Sample Data:

```
Firm SIC ETR
1   20  10
2   20  15
3   20  20
4   20  25
5   20  30
6   21  50
7   21  55
8   21  60
9   21  65
10  21  70
```

Should Become:

```
Firm SIC ETR ETR_Median
1   20  10  22.5
2   20  15  22.5
3   20  20  20
4   20  25  17.5
5   20  30  17.5
6   21  50  62.5
7   21  55  62.5
8   21  60  60
9   21  65  57.5
10  21  70  57.5
```

So, firm #4, for example, have an industry (SIC) median of 17.5 when only considering the other firms in the same industry (SIC).

Answer (score 2):

Consider splitting by *SIC* groups and run across all its *Firm* values to exclude from `median` calculation. Specifically, using:

- `by` (for grouping into subset dfs)
- `sapply` (to iterate across *Firm* values and call `median`)
- `unlist` (to convert list to vector for df column binding)

Altogether:

```
df$ETR_median <- unlist(by(df, df$SIC, function(sub)
    sapply(sub$Firm, function(f) median(sub$ETR[sub$Firm != f]))
))

df

#    Firm SIC ETR ETR_median
# 1     1  20  10       22.5
# 2     2  20  15       22.5
# 3     3  20  20       20.0
# 4     4  20  25       17.5
# 5     5  20  30       17.5
# 6     6  21  50       62.5
# 7     7  21  55       62.5
# 8     8  21  60       60.0
# 9     9  21  65       57.5
# 10   10  21  70       57.5
```

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that excludes the current observation before conducting the median calculation:

```
median_excl <- function(x){
  # pre-allocate our result vector:
  med_excl <- vector(length = length(x))
  # loop through our vector, excluding the current index and taking the median:
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    x_excl <- x[-i]
    med <- median(x_excl)

    med_excl[i] <- med
  }
  return(med_excl)
}
```

Then simply apply it using dplyr or however you chose:

```
df %>% group_by(SIC) %>% mutate(ETR_Median = median_excl(ETR))

#    Firm SIC ETR ETR_median
# 1     1  20  10       22.5
# 2     2  20  15       22.5
# 3     3  20  20       20.0
# 4     4  20  25       17.5
# 5     5  20  30       17.5
# 6     6  21  50       62.5
# 7     7  21  55       62.5
# 8     8  21  60       60.0
# 9     9  21  65       57.5
# 10   10  21  70       57.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris!